# Show that formula is backwards stable

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Have to prove the backwards stability of the following equations:

$$x+y$$ $$x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$ with the norm $$\mid \mid \cdot \mid \mid_{\infty} $$

$$x \cdot y$$ $$x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$ with the norm $$\mid \mid \cdot \mid \mid_{\infty} $$

Tried to look up the for the backwards stabiltiy which should be
$\frac{|\bar{x}-x|}{|x|} \leq O\left(\epsilon_{\text {machine}}\right)$

Simply don't know how to apply it.
Some advice would be good.

Thanks

Comment: Simply don't know what application you are attempting to do with it. Some details would be good.

Comment: that's all i got showing if it's backwards stable or not

Comment: so seperated x+y backwards stability same for x-y

Comment: This is pretty clearly an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You think you know what you want for an answer, but are misundertanding the nature of the problem. What you are saying doesn't quite make sense. I am trying to extract enough information about your real problem to figure out what you really need, but so far, you have only repeated your misunderstanding. If you would please describe what you are actually attempting to do, then hopefully with enough context, I or someone else can figure out how to give you a useful answer.

Comment: Backwards stability (Numerical stability)

Comment: Repeating yourself doesn't help.

Comment: Don't get it what you mean. I've provided all information i have. I don't know how to proof if the 2 formulas are backwards stable or not. I don't know if my researched formula for that is correct or not. And i don't know how to apply it on the 2 equations x+y or x-y

Comment: could probably be the oplus and ominus instead of + and -

Answer (score 1):

Let $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ denote the floating point representation of $x$ and $y$. If $x$ and $y$ are in the representable range, then $$\hat{x} = x(1+\delta_x), \quad |\delta_x| \leq u$$ and $$\hat{y} = y(1 + \delta_y), \quad |\delta_y| \leq u$$ where $u$ us the unit roundoff. If $\hat{x} + \hat{y}$ does not overflow, then the computed value of the sum $s = x+y$ satisfies
$$ \hat{s} = (\hat{x} + \hat{y})(1 + \delta_s), \quad |\delta_s| \leq u.$$
It follows that 
$$
\hat{s} = x(1+ \delta_x)(1 + \delta_s) + y(1+\delta_y)(1+\delta_s)
$$
We see that the computed sum is the exact sum of two numbers $\tilde{x}$ and $\tilde{y}$ given by
$$ \tilde{x} = x(1+ \delta_x)(1 + \delta_s)$$ 
and 
$$ \tilde{y} = y(1+\delta_y)(1+\delta_s).$$
We have
$$ \left|\frac{x - \tilde{x}}{x}\right| \leq 2u + u^2 = O(u)$$
and similarly for $y$. We conclude that the addition of real numbers in the representational range is backward stable.

---

I have to stress that there are good reasons for assuming that the input arguments are exact, i.e, we would normally have $\delta_x = \delta_y = 0$.